# App not working upgrading sencha touch from 2.0 to 2.1.1

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, upgrade, sencha-touch-2.1

```
Ext.define('Test.view.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    xtype: 'mainview',      
    config: {
    scrollable:'vertical',
        fullscreen: true,
        items: [{
            xtype:'toolbar',
            title:'Timesheets',
            docked:'top',
            cls:'toolbarcls',
            items:[{
                xtype:'button',
                cls:'toolbarcls buttoncls',
                iconCls:'more',
                iconMask:true,
                handler:function(){
                    Ext.Msg.alert("Left Button Pressed");
                }
                //text:'tet'
            },
            {xtype: 'spacer'},
            {
                xtype:'button',
                cls:'toolbarcls buttoncls addbutton',
                text:'ADD',
                handler:function(){
                    Ext.Msg.alert("Right Button Pressed");
                }

            }]

        },{
            xtype:'calendar'

        },{
            xtype:'panel',
            width:'100%',
            id:'datepanel',
            cls:'bgcolor',


        },{
            xtype:'list',
                id:'thelist',
                height:'50px', width:'100%',left:0,

            data: [
                {name: 'Shawshank Redemption', number: 5},
                {name: 'SuperBad', number: 3},
                {name: 'God Father', number: 5},
                {name: 'Forest Gump', number: 4.5},
                {name: 'A Beautiful Mind', number: 5}
            ],itemTpl: '{name}'
            }]

    }, 
    initialize: function() {
        this.callParent(arguments);
    },

    });
```

This piece of code works fine with sencha touch 2.0 but i upgraded to sencha touch 2.1.1 . Now list ovelaps on calender. what could be the problem.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a [layout](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/guide/layouts) to your config (just after 'fullscreen: true', for example):

```
layout: 'vbox',
```

If this does not work, the problem could be on 'calendar' object. I tried changing it for a 'textareafield' and it displayed properly.